# Image as Background for UI

Tags: android

I am newbi in android world and working on an android app.

I have used many of buttons and image buttons in my app.

Now i want to replace them with an background image. (So i can make nice gui easily)

I know i can use view listener and i can find the clicked x and y coordinate from onclick method.

But I want to how can i find which part of the image was clicked. Because different phones have different resolutions how can i do this efficiently ?

And one more thing, Is it good to handle gui this way ? 
Thanks !

Comment: This is a bad practice since you have different sizes of screens

Comment: So what is an efficient way to improve ui ?

Comment: You can set a background for buttons, edit text. etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to set the initial window width and height before execution of other code and load an image of quality based on the screen size.  so for example you can have 3 sets of images of different size.  One for 5 inch screens and below.  Another for 7 inch tablets.  Another for 10 and possibly another super high quality image for anything above.  As many devices coming on in the near future are reaching resolutions much higher then previously developed for.  Just run code initially that detects the initial window size at hand and load image based on resolution of that device.  From their program as you plan to.

Also to jump on answer above.  Detect rotation event and adjust image accordingly.  and update accordingly.  You are adding more programming of course but no reason what you are asking could not be done.  Just a few extra events detection and you should be good to go to accomplish exactly what you are looking to do

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it is not good practice to handle the GUI this way. Mostly because android screen size is not standard and so you can never be sure that it will work perfectly in all the devices. You can ofcourse handle the events using onTouchListener and see which part of image was clicked from the coordinates in the MotionEvent Object. But, I would not recommend doing so.

Creating layouts of different screen sizes and handling the events using Buttons and ImageButtons will be good.

Answer (score 0):

you can use android:background attribute for background images in the layout xml files...

however you also can set the background of UI element programatically